# Disable a specific linter rule in Atom (for js-standard)

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

How do I tell an Atom linter, specifically [js-standard](https://atom.io/packages/linter-js-standard), to ignore a rule? I want it ignored project-wide, and I thought that I could achieve this with a package.json or a .eslintrc but I can't get either to work. The rule I want to disable is [camelcase](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase)

I should be able to do this in a package.json file, because the [js-standard](https://atom.io/packages/linter-js-standard) linter has an option called `honorStyleSettings`:

> Honors style settings defined in package.json.
>
> Current style settings supported:
>
> ignore
>   parser

What's the syntax of these settings?

Comment: Are you using Eslint?

Comment: I believe js-standard uses eslint under the hood? So I thought an eslint config file might work.

Comment: I would also like to know. As far as I understood, you cannot specify which rules to ignore in package.json, only  which files to ignore, and which parser to user (see https://github.com/feross/standard#how-do-i-ignore-files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, here's how to use `js-standard` in Atom while selectively disabling a certain rule.

1. Disable the `linter-js-standard` Atom package
2. Install `linter-eslint`
3. Add an `.eslintrc` file:

   ```
    {
      "extends": ["standard"],
      "rules": {
        "camelcase": 0
      }
    }
   ```

You may also need to install `standard` and `eslint` via `npm`, if you don't have them already.

Answer (score 1):

Using the default install, there is no way to do this in `linter-js-standard`. (I believe this was a conscious decision on the part of the module authors who believe that `standard` is a hard target rather than an ideal.)

If you wish to use eslint-style comments to disable linting for certain lines or code sections, install `babel-eslint` via `npm i --save-dev babel-eslint` and add

```
{
  ...
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
  ...
}
```

to your `package.json` file which will allow you to annotate your source as needed.

#### Example

Assuming `foo` is defined but not used elsewhere in your file, linter will warn: '*foo is assigned a value but never used. (no-unused-vars)*'

```
const foo = 1
```

After installing `babel-eslint`, configuring standard in your `package.json` file, and adding this comment, linter will ignore the line.

```
const foo = 1 // eslint-disable-line
```

See [Configuring ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) for other configuration annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to disable the "camelcase" rule by going to "linter-js-standard" package folder and adding to `node_modules/standard/eslintrc.json` file the following line:

```
"rules": { "camelcase": [0] }
```

So the entire "eslintrc.json" looks like:

```
{
  "extends": ["standard", "standard-jsx"],
  "rules": { "camelcase": [0] }
}
```

Just save or edit your .js file in Atom for the changes to take effect.

On my Linux desktop the full path to `eslintrc.json` is:

```
~/.atom/packages/linter-js-standard/node_modules/standard/eslintrc.json
```

Of course, when you update the "linter-js-standard" package in Atom, you'll have to do the above steps again.

To turn the "camelcase" rule on you may change the `"camelcase"` value to `[2]` instead of deleting the entire "rules" line:

```
"rules": { "camelcase": [2] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is ESlint that your plugin uses then create a `.eslintrc` file in the root of your project & write your rules within there.

Heres an example of a `.eslintrc` file [github example](https://gist.github.com/cletusw/e01a85e399ab563b1236). I find i need to close and reopen Atom to refresh the lint errors

**EDIT:**

showEslintRules (default: false). You will need to change this option to true.

Comment: Not working I'm afraid, I guess it doesn't respect the .eslintrc file. I should be able to customise it using package.json but I have no idea what the syntax is.

Comment: For me this worked with the package linter-eslint, but not with linter-js-standard.