# How to disable a specific linter rule in .eslintrc?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, eslint

I saved the [this .eslintrc](https://gist.github.com/cletusw/e01a85e399ab563b1236) in the root of my project in Atom Editor, but the behaviour of the linter-js-standard package does not change, even after a restart.

How can I disable specific rules, e.g. no-extra-semi?

I already tried Mark's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426512/disable-a-specific-linter-rule-in-atom-for-js-standard), but it is not working for me.

Comment: Why not `linter-eslint`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I did not about know linter-eslint, but I managed to set it up for ES6, Babel and JSX. Using this package, .eslintrc is properly taken into account and I can disable specific rules.

Comment: Yes, if you could expand upon how to make sure that an Atom linter package is taking .eslintrc into account, that would be most satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a linter package for `eslint` called `linter-eslint` that will work directly with your `.eslintrc` files.

This package will use the `.eslintrc` in your root project directory by default. If that is absent, it will then use the one specified in your `package.json`.

After installing `linter-eslint`, on the `packages` tab you can click on the `settings` for `linter-eslint`. In this page there is an option for `eslintrc Path`. You can use this setting to specify an `.eslintrc` file other than the one in your project root directory or in your `package.json`. You can also customize the eslint Rules or to disable when no eslint config file is found.