# hide mixed tabs and spaces error in atom editor esLint package

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, eslint

Hi I am using Atom editor to create React based application, i have installed eslint package and since then i am getting "mixed spaces and tabs" error, marked with red lines, need help in how to disable those errors.

Comment: Try right clicking on the file in the file tree on the left and selecting 'beautify' - not sure, but this might remove your tabs for you

Comment: Hi Brett, i can't find any option 'beautify' on right clicking the file in file tree.

Comment: Sorry Rajan, it looks like it must have been an Atom package that I added https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable a specific linter rule in Atom (for js-standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426512/disable-a-specific-linter-rule-in-atom-for-js-standard)